# How to replace a zero integer with an empty string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code I would like the `CHAC` to show an empty string so that I can concatenate it with similar strings later.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.id = random.randint(self.min_hit_points, self.max_hit_points)
    self.level = random.randint(self.min_level, self.max_level)
    self.CHAC = str(int(self.id / 5 - 1 * (self.level - 1))) 
    self.color = random.choice(COLORS)
```

Comment: The easy way is `self.CHAC = "" if self.CHAC=='0' else self.CHAC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since integer zero is falsy, you can do

```
str(int(self.id / 5 - 1 * (self.level - 1)) or '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
value = int(self.id/5-1*(self.level-1))
self.CHAC = '' if value == 0 else str(value)
```